# I Have Problem with phone authentication SHA 1 signing key. When I upload My apk on Google play store Then It give error

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, one-time-password

I Have Problem with phone authentication SHA 1 signing key. When I upload My apk on Google play store Then It give erroe.

You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate. You must use the same certificate. The upload certificate has fingerprint:
SHA1: 95:3C:93:2E:8D:48:2E:76:9E:77:55:67:5A:2C:00:1F:D4:BF:84:4B
and the certificate used to sign the APK you uploaded has fingerprint:
SHA1: 43:2F:A9:4D:3E:B4:D1:BD:DD:49:21:21:10:08:26:B6:21:3A:CC:20[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDoZ3.jpg)

Comment: You didn't use the correct jks key for release APK.

Comment: sir I upload first time on google play. It is not updated app. First time upload. I dont Know hot to generate release signed sha1. I try many videos but it is not useful. kindly help that..

Comment: Generate JKS key then generate release apk from generated jks key
https://medium.com/publishous/generate-a-signed-release-apk-file-in-android-studio-3ae4775beace

Comment: Sir I could not found release Sha1. I attatched my app with firebase for phone authentication. But i not found realase Sha1 for app publish on google play. It gave me error. That sha1 not correct. How i found sha1 for publish app on google play.???

Comment: do you have jks for release?